# A shorter version of the wording "from this point onwards"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What is a shorter version of the wording ***"from this point onwards"*** when we talk about some part of a document or program code? Possible context:

> From this point onwards we assume that all input data has been fully
> verified.

*(meaning: we've checked all input data with the help of the above program code and starting from this line of code we don't need to re-check it anymore)*

Is it possible to say just ***"here onwards"*** or ***"here ahead"*** instead of ***"from this point onwards"***? Or maybe any other shorter form?

Comment: Henceforth,....; Beginning now,...; As of now... From now on,...

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty, thank you! Maybe you'll post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Ok, it's posted.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty, thanks, it's upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options are:

Henceforth,...
Beginning now,...
Starting now,...
As of now,...
From now on,...

*Now* could be replaced by *today*, or by a future date, if that fits.

These are options having to do with time.
More directly to your question about a point in computer code,
you can use "henceforth" or "from here on", but you might want to mention a certain line or statement in the code so that there is no confusion.

Comment: Are all these options applicable in the meaning of "from this place in the text", and not "from this time"?

Comment: I've clarified the meaning of the example in my question.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky  For that use, I would say that "from this point on,..." is quite good, or "from here on,...". "Henceforth,..." works too, in that sense. You could also say "after this point in the code", to make it clear that you don't mean beginning at this point in the text you  are writing, but at that point in the code.

Comment: It seems my answer wasn't quite to the point of your question; sorry about that. I am editing the answer.

Comment: thanks again! As for mention a certain line, it's usually not a problem, because this phrase in program code can only be as a comment so it's clear that we're talking about the line with this comment.

Comment: Ok, understood.